# How do I display my form in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to display my stat update form in my Django template, however it isn't displaying. My stats below show up correctly, just not the form.

```
{{ stats.user }} | {{ stats.weight }} | {{ stats.date }}
```

Template:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h1>My Health</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-auto text-center p-3 form-group">
        <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
            {{ update_form }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-signup btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto text-center p-3">
            <p class="text-center"> {{ stats.user }} | {{ stats.weight }} | {{ stats.date }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py:

```
class StatUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Stats
        fields = ('user', 'weight', 'date')
```

models.py:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'health_stats'
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"You currently weigh {self.weight}, {self.user}"
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Stats
from .forms import StatUpdateForm
from django.views import generic, View
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
# from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
# from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# from .forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


class MyHealth(View):
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        stats = Stats
             
        context = {
            'stats': stats,
            "update_form": StatUpdateForm(),
            'user': stats.user,
            'weight': stats.weight,
            'date': stats.date,
        }
        return render(request, 'MyHealth.html', context)
```

I've tried redefining the form in my views.py, but I'm unsure why it isn't pulling through, as the other parts of the context are.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you're import forms twice.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean

Comment: Oh, I see. You commented out the second import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the form fields are rendering and the fields just aren't loaded with the correct values.
do this: `StatUpdateForm(instance=stats)` to make it an edit form

Answer (score 1):

In the form, since you are using a model, you must extend from forms.ModelForm instead forms.Form, try to change that line in the forms.py

```py
class StatUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):  # extends from forms.ModelForm
    class Meta:
        model = Stats
        fields = ('user', 'weight', 'date')
```